# Nginx disable logging for certain user agents

Tags: nginx, user-agent

Basically, I'm trying to remove search engine crawlers such as Google, Bing, and what not from my access logs. They really build up over time, eventually adding hundreds of thousands of useless access log entries to the logs, this is especially a pain if you ever have to search through them. The trouble I'm having is that in my blocks, I'm defining the access log, therefore Nginx is just looking at that and ignoring my 2nd one that I define in the location / block. If I comment out my access log for my site (not the crawler block) then it works fine. Here is the configuration:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
access_log  /home/domains/example.com/logs/access;
error_log /home/domains/example.com/logs/error;
root /home/domains/example.com/forums;
location / {
        index index.html index.htm;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* ("googlebot") ) {
        access_log off;
        }
}
```

I've removed everything except that upon posting (php include, and what not), though I've checked that nothing is interfering it by commenting everything out everything except what is above. So to sum it up, I have a log defined in my virtual block to log all of the traffic (I have it defined for every block, to make it neater and what not. I'm trying to disable logging for certain user agents, unless I disable the main log for the site, it'll continue logging what I tell it not to for the user agents.

I've been at this for a few hours now, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

You should not use `if` statements in `nginx` - [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)

Use [conditional logging](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/):

```
http {

     map $http_user_agent $excluded_ua {
         ~Googlebot  0;
         default     1;
     }
     .......
}

server {

     access_log  /home/domains/example.com/logs/access combined if=$excluded_ua;

}
```

However be careful about excluding `googlebot` as some abusive bots disguise themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually the regex `("googlebot")` will match a user agent *with* double quotes, clearly not what you want. Drop the parentheses, and the quotes if you want, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue I'm having isn't the matching of the user agent. Rather, for some reason I can't turn off logging for said user-agent, unless I remove the defined log location for my block.

Comment: It looks me that matching the user agent is the issue, because `access_log` won't be executed unless the regex matches. I also tested it out using conf similar to yours and it worked just fine.

Comment: I realize I don't have the syntax totally correct yet, but it is enough to pick Google up. For example, if I throw in a "return 403" after the access_log, it'll return the 403, but the logging remains, unless I remove the log I defined for all of the requests on that server block.

Comment: What nginx version are you using?

Comment: Just like mine. Just to be clear, you're still using this `("googlebot")` unchanged, right?

Comment: I've tried changing it, the problem doesn't appear to be the regex (though I'm sure the original one probably isn't correct). Nginx is picking it up, I can tell because if I throw a "return 403" in there, Google throws an error (using Google webmaster tools). If I remove the access_log directive from the top of my block, it'll stop logging. So I suspect Nginx is only looking at the top one, and ignoring the one within the if statement.

I've tried pretty much everything, disabling all other blocks, changing the order, etc.

Comment: Well, I do my tests by sending the UA through curl, but I doubt that could be how I get the expected result. I have nothing more to contribute, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add return 200; after access_log off;

so it looks like this:

```
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "(googlebot)" ) {
        access_log off;
        return 200;
    }
}
```